# JavaFX - centered Text in Scene

Tags: java, javafx, alignment

I've got a JavaFX `Text`,`Scene` and `Group`

```
Text waitingForKey
Scene scene
Group root
```

I have a string String `waitingForKeyString` which I'm adding to `waitingForKey`and I want to have a center align.

The problem is that sometimes the string has two sentences and I can't aligned it

```
 String waitingForKeyString= " Level 2 \n\n" + "Press ENTER to start a new game";
```

OR

String waitingForKeyString= "  Press ENTER \n"+
                            "to start the game", messageString="";

THEN

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root,SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, Color.BLACK);
waitingForKey.setText(waitingForKeyString);
root.getChildren().add(waitingForKey);
```

So how could I align this to center? When I tried to align first `waitingForKeyString`I destroyed the second `waitingForKeyString and vicecersa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) as root of your `Scene` as it has an [`alignmentProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#alignmentProperty).

If you want individually align `Nodes` in the `StackPane` you can use [`public static void setAlignment(Node child, Pos value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#setAlignment-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Pos-) method of `StackPane`.

**Example (one Text is aligned in CENTER, another one is aligned in TOP LEFT)**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            Text text2 = new Text("I will be aligned TOPLEFT");
            Text text = new Text(" Level 2 \n\n" + "Press ENTER to start a new game");
            text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            root.getChildren().addAll(text2, text);
            StackPane.setAlignment(text2, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
            StackPane.setAlignment(text, Pos.CENTER);


            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what should i do if i want to add a text to the TopLeft too? It aligns everything to center. Should I make another StackPane and then merge them togheter?

Comment: Updated the example for you with two Texts, one is aligned CENTER, one is TOP LEFT.

Answer (score 3):

Specify `TextAlignment.CENTER` for the [`Text`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) and use a layout like [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) that "defaults to `Pos.CENTER`."

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37541777/230513
 */
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Text waitingForKey = new Text("Level 2 \n\n" + "Press ENTER to start a new game");
        waitingForKey.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        waitingForKey.setFont(new Font(18));
        waitingForKey.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(waitingForKey);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ trashgod And if I want to move a text to TopLeft? Should I create another StackPane? Or can I somehow move every child?

Comment: DVarga's [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37541701/230513) correctly combines our suggested approaches.