# Binding Text Using JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, text, bind, pane

I was just wondering how to bind text to the center of a pane in JavaFx.

Code I wrote in program:

```
Text text1 = new Text("test");

text1.xProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
text1.yProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));
```

Nothing was outputted. What is wrong with this and how would I bind it so if the user resizes the window the text will stay in the center?

Comment: Use a `StackPane`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX - centered Text in Scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541279/javafx-centered-text-in-scene)